# how can we tell delayed_job when a delayed task fails so it will auto-retry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

Our app is hosted on heroku and we use delayed job when sending info to a remote system (via a GET to a url with some url params)

the remote system returns a success code usually, but it it;s real busy it returns a tryagain code.

suppose the our method is

```
def send_info
   the_url = "http://mydomain.com/dosomething?arg=#{self.someval}"
   the_result = open(the_url).read
   successflag = get_success_flag_from(the_result)
end
```

and so somewhere in our code we do

```
@widget.delay.send_info
```

and that all works fine.

Except it does not automatically handle the case where the remote said to try back later.

Is there any way for the send_info method (which is what delayed job will execute) to "tell" delayed_job "retry me again"? Do we need to throw some custom exception or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raising any kind of exception ought to cause delayed_job to requeue it (subject to only-trying-so-many-times); if you don't especially need a custom exception you can just raise a `RuntimeError`.

Comment: interesting, thanks! does our method have access to the number of tries that have been attempted already? I know that # is in the delayed_job table, but it's not clear to me how a method/instance could determine WHICH entry in the table is associated with that method/instance.